# Using for-of / for each array of states to manipulate dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering how I would automate the below in a kind of for-of way.

If I want to perform the same test and action for many specific states (not all), how would I go about doing something like

```
var anArray = [firstName, lastName];

for (anArray as Q){
  if(this.state.Q.length > 1 || this.state.Q.length == 0){
    document.getElementById(toString(Q)).className="someClass";
  }else{
    document.getElementById(toString(Q)).className="AnOtherClass";
  }
}
```

in this return:

```
return function(e) {
  var state = {};
  state[key] = e.target.value;
  this.setState(state, () => {

    if(validate(this.state.dob)){
      document.getElementById("dob").className="inputYay";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("dob").className="inputErr";
    }

    //firstName
    if(this.state.firstName.length > 1 || this.state.firstName.length == 0){
      document.getElementById("firstName").className="inputYay";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("firstName").className="inputErr";
    }

    //lastName
    if(this.state.lastName.length > 1 || this.state.lastName.length == 0){
      document.getElementById("lastName").className="inputYay";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("lastName").className="inputErr";
    }

  }
  );
}
```

Ultimately I would like only to check the key of each state provided by the return function, but I cant get my head around how that would work as I am validating different types of responses.

I would greatly appreciate either method for my understanding.

many thanks as always :

Comment: this is hard to understand what you want to do. Maybe you can simplify your question? Except `setState` we don't see much React-related code here

Comment: Are the `dob`, `firstName`, and `lastName` inputs getting rendered by React? If so you probably want to use something like [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#usage-with-reactjs)

Comment: Hi @Jack. The input fields are being manipulated and rendered onChange, however this works well.

Comment: @SebastienLorber Sorry i'm not very clear. I want to create a conditional function which will run a foreach with *something* like the first example, so I can put any number of inputs through it without having to rewrite a new function for each state. The reason is that I will have many similar tests to perform on a host of different inputs.

Comment: Also, the above runs on every input event. This is to live update the view upon every keypress.